# Acceptable Range Highlighting of Background in Chart.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm working on building a simple line chart using Chart.js (the 2.0.2 beta) and I'd like to highlight a particular range of the chart's background to highlight an "acceptable range".

Here's an example of what I'm wanting to recreate via Charts.js: 
[image: Acceptable Range Example]

If it's helpful,  here's what I've got working so far.  It's pretty rudimentary. Any guidance or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
var bgdata = {
     labels: ["12:00 AM", "1:00 AM", "2:00 AM", "3:00 AM", "4:00 AM", "5:00 AM", "6:00 AM", "7:00 AM", "8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM", "9:00 PM", "10:00 PM", "11:00 PM"],
    datasets: [
    {
    label: "Average Hourly Blood Glucose Reading", 
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 9, 158,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(29, 9, 158,1)",
    data: [213, 199, 208, 191, 205, 181, 163, 133, 129, 186, 184, 137, 125, 126, 119, 120, 129, 133, 122, 156, 203, 207, 183, 211]
        }
    ]
 };

var bgChart = document.getElementById('bg').getContext('2d');
var bgLineChart = Chart.Line(bgChart, {
    data: bgdata,
    options: {
        scaleFontSize: 12,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {min: 25, max: 250, stepSize: 25}
                }],
            },
        title: {display: true, text: 'Average Hourly Blood Glucose'},           
    }});
```

Comment: You can join the Chart.js Slack community and get some help there. https://chartjs-slack-automation.herokuapp.com

Comment: Highlighting of ranges could be accomplished using chartjs annotation plugin; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342556/multiple-range-highlighting-of-background-in-chart-js/49445264# or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372827/chart-js-color-specific-parts-of-the-background-in-a-line-chart/49379130#49379130

Answer (score 12):

The following implements the required functionality in Chart.js 2.* (uses Chart.js 2.1.4, which is the current version at the time of writing):

https://jsfiddle.net/742zut83/22/

The implementation is based on extending the line chart type and overriding the `draw` function. The new `draw` function checks whether within the line chart's `data` exists the following, which defines the y-range to highlight:

```
yHighlightRange : {
  begin: 6.5,
  end: 12.5
}
```

If it does not exist, then the original `draw` function is called. If it exists, then a rectangle spanning from the left to the right and within the y-range specified is drawn. After the rectangle is drawn, the original `draw` function is called, in order to complete the drawing of the line chart.

The first implementation did not draw a rectangle. Among other deficiencies it had, it drew all pixel-lines separately. Like TV scanlines (yes, I'm old). But the old code is here (in case you care about line drawing):

https://jsfiddle.net/742zut83/17/

The current code is as follows:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

// The original draw function for the line chart. This will be applied after we have drawn our highlight range (as a rectangle behind the line chart).
var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
// Extend the line chart, in order to override the draw function.
Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    var chart = this.chart;
    // Get the object that determines the region to highlight.
    var yHighlightRange = chart.config.data.yHighlightRange;

    // If the object exists.
    if (yHighlightRange !== undefined) {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

      var yRangeBegin = yHighlightRange.begin;
      var yRangeEnd = yHighlightRange.end;

      var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

      var yRangeBeginPixel = yaxis.getPixelForValue(yRangeBegin);
      var yRangeEndPixel = yaxis.getPixelForValue(yRangeEnd);

      ctx.save();

      // The fill style of the rectangle we are about to fill.
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)';
      // Fill the rectangle that represents the highlight region. The parameters are the closest-to-starting-point pixel's x-coordinate,
      // the closest-to-starting-point pixel's y-coordinate, the width of the rectangle in pixels, and the height of the rectangle in pixels, respectively.
      ctx.fillRect(xaxis.left, Math.min(yRangeBeginPixel, yRangeEndPixel), xaxis.right - xaxis.left, Math.max(yRangeBeginPixel, yRangeEndPixel) - Math.min(yRangeBeginPixel, yRangeEndPixel));

      ctx.restore();
    }

    // Apply the original draw function for the line chart.
    originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    }],
    // This, if it exists at all, defines the highlight region.
    yHighlightRange: {
      begin: 6.5,
      end: 12.5
    }
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I'm new to javascript, but multiple areas could be drawn by making yrangebegin and end arrays, then iterating the stuff in the if statement yrangebegin.length times, correct?

Comment: Looks like I was correct. I made a couple of edits to allow multiple areas: https://jsfiddle.net/fahd2mga/4/

Comment: @JohnMoffitt You are correct, but you could go at it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/742zut83/27/. The object has become an array of objects (and plural instead of singular).  Now you could use a different color in each object, by using a `color` member after each `end` member. Without needing a third array for colors and changing less in the code, I believe. I also took some common code outside the loop.

Comment: Here's one that allows for multiple colors as well: https://jsfiddle.net/fahd2mga/5/

Comment: @JohnMoffitt ;) Have fun!

Comment: I ended up placing @xnakos code inside componentDidUpdate() callback. See my anster.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Box Annotations](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation#box-annotations) from chartjs-plugin-annotation (official from chartjs). Specify `yMin` & `yMax`, and leave `xMin` & `xMax` undefined so that it fills the entire x-axis.

Example code:

```js
var chartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    type: "line",
    label: "Dataset 1",
    data: [10,-20,40,45,15,5,20,20],
    fill: false
  }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        drawTime: "beforeDatasetsDraw",
        type: "box",
        xScaleID: "x-axis-0",
        yScaleID: "y-axis-0",
        borderWidth: 0,
        yMin: 25,
        yMax: 40,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(46, 204, 113,0.3)"
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chart.js v2.0.2 doesn't provide this functionality out of the box.

You can however extend or create new type constructors. See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-extending-existing-chart-types.

You should be able to implement either an area type that is bounded by two lines, or you could create a threshold band similar to [xnakos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37738100/796127) answer.

Answer (score 0):

this code will be helpful

```
var bgdata = {

        datasets: [
        {
        label: "Average Hourly Blood Glucose Reading", 
        fill: false,

       data: [
            {
                "y": 213,
                "x": 0,
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(29, 9, 158,0.2)",
            "label":"12:00 AM"

            },
            {
                "y": 199,
                "x": 1,
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(29, 9, 158,0.4)",
            "label":"1:00 AM"

            },
        {
                "y": 208,
                "x": 2,
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(29, 9, 158,0.6)",
            "label":"2:00 AM"

            }
        ]
            }
        ]
     };
```

Comment: Thanks, @sadik-ali,  but this doesn't seem to be working out for me.  I replaced my bgdata (and commented out all my chart-specific options) with your suggestion above to see how it worked, and I'm getting errors in the console:

* Chart.min.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
* Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing @xnakos code inside componentDidUpdate() callback. The advantage is that you should not set the opacity of the highlighted area to visible the graph like ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)' and no need to overwrite the fill method in @xnakos answer.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDraw: (chartInstance) => {
      var chart = chartInstance;
      // Get the object that determines the region to highlight.
      var yHighlightRange = chart.config.data.yHighlightRange;

      // If the object exists.
      if (yHighlightRange !== undefined) {
        var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

        var yRangeBegin = yHighlightRange.begin;
        var yRangeEnd = yHighlightRange.end;

        var xaxis = chart.scales["x-axis"];
        var yaxis = chart.scales["y-axis"];

        var yRangeBeginPixel = yaxis.getPixelForValue(yRangeBegin);
        var yRangeEndPixel = yaxis.getPixelForValue(yRangeEnd);

        ctx.save();

        // The fill style of the rectangle we are about to fill.
        ctx.fillStyle = yHighlightRange.fillStyle;
        // Fill the rectangle that represents the highlight region. The parameters are the closest-to-starting-point pixel's x-coordinate,
        // the closest-to-starting-point pixel's y-coordinate, the width of the rectangle in pixels, and the height of the rectangle in pixels, respectively.
        ctx.fillRect(
          xaxis.left,
          Math.min(yRangeBeginPixel, yRangeEndPixel),
          xaxis.right - xaxis.left,
          Math.max(yRangeBeginPixel, yRangeEndPixel) -
            Math.min(yRangeBeginPixel, yRangeEndPixel)
        );

        ctx.restore();
      }
    },
  });
}
```

and the data object is as follow,

```
data = {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [...],
  yHighlightRange: {
    begin: 50,
    end: 100,
    fillStyle: "#7DD8D2",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the recent versions of Chart JS, you can use Box Annotation. You can read more about it here: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/types/box.html