# echarts yaxis splitArea interval

Tags: range, highlighting, echarts

I want to color yaxis from value `x` to `y` with some color,
I used `splitArea` but  is no use to me because is a `splitArea`  is a repeater, repeats color based on given interval.

I want to obtain something similar to Chart.js:

> [Acceptable Range Highlighting of Background in Chart.js 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685745/acceptable-range-highlighting-of-background-in-chart-js-2-0)

[echart](http://jsfiddle.net/kp52h2br/6/)

```
 yAxis: {
  splitArea:{
     show:true,
     areaStyle:{
      color:["rgba(255,0,0,0.7)",'yellow','green','green','green']
      }
    }
},
```